# How To skip the Duplicate price items while adding to cart?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to add the items to the cart which are not same Price Items below is my code:

```
List<WebElement> priceSpans = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-product-mini']//a//span[(contains(text(),'$')) and not(contains(@class,'priceTag-discount'))]"));
List<Double> priceOfProducts = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (WebElement webElement : priceSpans)
{
    String priceText = webElement.getText();
    if (priceText != null && priceText.length() > 0)
    {
        Double priceValue = Double.parseDouble(priceText.replace('$', ' ').trim());
        priceOfProducts.add(priceValue);
        System.out.println("The PLP Products Price are:" + priceValue);
    }
}
```

Using the above code to print the price and below is the output:

> The PLP Products Price are:69.99 
>  The PLP Products Price are:64.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:59.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:54.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:49.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:59.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:39.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:79.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:119.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:69.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:79.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:119.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:69.99 
> The PLP Products Price are:119.99

So there are duplicate prices so how do I skip the duplicate one and how do I choose only one from the duplicate (i.e 2 products contains the same price ex:59.99 )

Comment: Checks if `priceValue` already exists in `priceOfProducts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest Solution, Just keep adding Current `priceText` to dummy String `stringSoFar`, and then check if that pricetext is already present in `stringSoFar`:

```
    String stringSoFar="";
    int counter=0; 

    for (WebElement webElement : priceSpans){ 

        List<WebElement> refreshedPriceSpans = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-product-mini']//a//span[(contains(text(),'$')) and not(contains(@class,'priceTag-discount'))]"));   //to avoid stale exception

        String priceText = refreshedPriceSpans.get(counter).getText(); 

        stringSoFar = stringSoFar + priceText; 

        if (priceText != null && priceText.length() > 0 && !stringSoFar.contains(priceText)) 
            { 
Double priceValue = Double.parseDouble(priceText.replace('$', ' ').trim()); 
              priceOfProducts.add(priceValue); 
              System.out.println("The PLP Products Price are:"+ priceValue); 
            } 

           counter++;
         }
```

Comment: I have used the suggested code but getting the "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" exception for second iteration

Comment: priceSpans = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-product-mini']//a//span[(contains(text(),'$')) and not(contains(@class,'priceTag-discount'))]"));
List<Double> priceOfProducts = new ArrayList<Double>();
Set<String> prices = new HashSet<String>();
for (WebElement webElement : priceSpans) {String priceText =webElement.getText();

Comment: if (priceText != null && priceText.length() > 0 && !prices.contains(priceText)) {Double priceValue = Double.parseDouble(priceText.replace('$',').trim());priceOfProducts.add(priceValue); elementUtils.safeJavaScriptClick(quickViewAddtoCart);
getDriver().navigate().back(); elementUtils.waitForPageLoaded(getDriver());  }
prices.add(priceText);
    }

Comment: @user3538483: I've updated the above answer with changes to address StaleException

Comment: Thanks a LOT now able to get the value and able to continue.

Answer (score 1):

what about if we use Set, it self avoid duplicate values, where we can minimize if conditions

```
 Set<Double> priceOfProducts = new HashSet<Double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map to avoid duplicate prices, check example code below. 
In the map `key` is price and `value` is WebElement.

```
List<WebElement> priceSpans = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='m-product-mini']//a//span[(contains(text(),'$')) and not(contains(@class,'priceTag-discount'))]"));
HashMap<Double, WebElement> priceOfProducts = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < priceSpans.size(); i++) {
    Double priceValue = Double.parseDouble(priceSpans.get(i).getText().replace('$', ' ').trim());
    priceOfProducts.put(priceValue, priceSpans.get(i));
    //System.out.println("The PLP Products Price are: " + priceValue);
}

priceOfProducts.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("The PLP Products Price are: " + k));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing before we get started, with your current code `priceText` is never going to equal `null` or be zero length because your XPath requires at least a '$' so you can remove the `if` check.

After that, you should take some time to look into Java [`streams`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). You can use them to do all kinds of collection processing, etc. like what you are doing here. Explanation of the different steps are in the code comments below.

```
By locator = By.xpath("//div[@class='m-product-mini']//a//span[(contains(text(),'$')) and not(contains(@class,'priceTag-discount'))]");
List<Double> priceOfProducts = getDriver().findElements(locator)
    .stream()                                      // turns the collection of WebElements into a stream
    .map(e -> e.getText().replace("$", "").trim()) // turns the collection of WebElements into a collection of string (from .getText()), removes the '$', and trim()s
    .distinct()                                    // removes duplicates
    .map(e -> Double.parseDouble(e))               // converts String to Double
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                 // the final piece... returns a List<Double>
priceOfProducts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Since we don't have the original HTML, I mocked up some HTML with some different prices, extra whitespace all over, including one duplicate

```
<div id="base">
    <span>  $0.99 </span>
    <span>$1.99  </span>
    <span> $1.99   </span>
    <span>  $2.99 </span>
</div>
```

When I run the code on the HTML above (with an appropriate locator, `By.cssSelector("#base > span")`), I get the output

```
0.99
1.99
2.99
```

NOTE: You will need to add an import for the `stream` related code, `import java.util.stream.Collectors;`. Your IDE should help you with this but just in case...

Comment: I Am able to print the price values but how do I write the If condition to add the product to cart?

Comment: You'll have to explain more because I don't have enough context of what you are trying to do. Please create a new question with all the specifics. You can message me here with the new question and I'll take a look, if you want.